Error when installing tensorflow_federated package in VS code in Windows 10
I want to install tensorflow_federated package in VS Code in Windows 10 by using 'pip install tensorflow_federated' command. My python version is 3.9.0. But I get this error:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (e:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.48.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting absl-py==1.*,>=1.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached absl_py-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting attrs~=21.4 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
Collecting cachetools~=3.1 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached cachetools-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting dm-tree==0.1.7 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached dm_tree-0.1.7-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting dp-accounting==0.3.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached dp_accounting-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting farmhashpy==0.4.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached farmhashpy-0.4.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (768 bytes)
Collecting grpcio~=1.46 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached grpcio-1.63.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tensorflow-federated to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.47.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.46.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.45.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.44.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.43.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.42.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.41.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of tensorflow-federated to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.40.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.39.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.38.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. 
See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.33.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting absl-py~=1.0.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached absl_py-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting dm-tree~=0.1.7 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached dm_tree-0.1.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
Collecting grpcio~=1.46.3 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached grpcio-1.46.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.32.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting attrs~=21.2.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.28.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.27.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting grpcio~=1.34.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached grpcio-1.34.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
Collecting jax~=0.2.27 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached jax-0.2.28.tar.gz (887 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting absl-py~=0.10 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached absl_py-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Collecting attrs~=19.3.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting grpcio~=1.32.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached grpcio-1.32.0.tar.gz (20.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting h5py~=2.10.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz (301 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tensorflow_federated
  Using cached tensorflow_federated-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting absl-py~=0.9.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting grpcio~=1.29.0 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached grpcio-1.29.0.tar.gz (19.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy~=1.18.4 (from tensorflow_federated)
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [90 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      <string>:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates    
      C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.14')
      C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py:77: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
      performance hint: _common.pyx:261:19: Exception check after calling 'random_func' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'random_func' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.        
      performance hint: _common.pyx:285:19: Exception check after calling 'random_func' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'random_func' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.        
      performance hint: _common.pyx:308:50: Exception check after calling 'random_func' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'random_func' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.        
      performance hint: _common.pyx:411:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:448:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:490:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:573:36: Exception check after calling 'f0' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f0' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:577:36: Exception check after calling 'f1' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f1' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:581:36: Exception check after calling 'f2' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f2' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:585:36: Exception check after calling 'f3' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f3' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:617:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:652:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:687:63: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:727:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:756:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:874:40: Exception check after calling 'f0' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f0' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:878:40: Exception check after calling 'fd' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'fd' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:882:41: Exception check after calling 'fdd' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'fdd' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:887:40: Exception check after calling 'fi' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'fi' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:891:41: Exception check after calling 'fdi' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'fdi' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:895:38: Exception check after calling 'fiii' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'fiii' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:930:31: Exception check after calling 'f' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _common.pyx:972:32: Exception check after calling 'f1' will always require the GIL to be acquired. Declare 'f1' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
      performance hint: _generator.pyx:811:41: Exception check after calling '_shuffle_int' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
      Possible solutions:
          1. Declare '_shuffle_int' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
          2. Use an 'int' return type on '_shuffle_int' to allow an error code to be returned.
      performance hint: _generator.pyx:840:45: Exception check after calling '_shuffle_int' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
      Possible solutions:
          1. Declare '_shuffle_int' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
          2. Use an 'int' return type on '_shuffle_int' to allow an error code to be returned.
     
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              for i in range(1, RK_STATE_LEN):
                  self.rng_state.key[i] = val[i]
              self.rng_state.pos = i
     
              self._bitgen.state = &self.rng_state
              self._bitgen.next_uint64 = &mt19937_uint64
                                         ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
     
      _mt19937.pyx:138:35: Cannot assign type 'uint64_t (*)(void *) except? -1 nogil' to 'uint64_t (*)(void *) noexcept nogil'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of the value being assigned.
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py", line 238, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py", line 234, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py", line 225, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py", line 191, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4agl8h49\numpy_9efb4db717984b279b7ee330bd9bf34f\tools\cythonize.py", line 80, in process_pyx
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "E:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['E:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'cython', '-3', '--fast-fail', '-o', '_mt19937.c', '_mt19937.pyx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Cythonizing sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main   
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "E:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i5dozbta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i5dozbta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\AlBaLoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i5dozbta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 488, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 469, in setup_package
        File "<string>", line 275, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Cython version is 0.29.37
Can anyone help me? I really need tensorflow_federated package.
Cython version was 3.0 and I downgraded to 0.29.37.But the error did not change.

This could be related to compatibility issues with dependencies. Did you start from a clean virtual environment ? If not then try that first.

I created a new virtual environment and run the command but I got that error again.
